# Dragging a td does not fire droppable event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to drop a td into a div in an another column. The droppable event does not fire when I drop the td in; no request is made to the controller. What am I doing wrong here?

Jquery/Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listProducts td').css({ 'z-index': 100 }).draggable({
        'opacity': '0.5',
        'revert': true,
        'cursor': 'pointer' 
    });

    function displayCart(data) {
        var s = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            s += '<br><video style="width:250px; height:150px;" src=' + data[i].Workout.link + ' controls> </video>';

            s += '<br>Name: ' + data[i].Workout.Name;

            s += '<br><a href="#?productIdCart=' + data[i].Workout.workout_id + '" class="delete">Delete</a>';
            s += '<br>--------------------------';
        }

        $('#cart').html(s);
    }

    $('#cart').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var productId = $(ui.draggable).siblings('.productId').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'Workouts/AddToCart/' + productId,
                success: function (data) {
                    displayCart(data);
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert('failure');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Delete Item
    $('#cart').ajaxComplete(function () {
        $('.delete').bind('click', function () {
            var productIdCart = $(this).attr('href').split('=');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'Workouts/DeleteFromCart/' + productIdCart[1],
                success: function (data) {
                    displayCart(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });


    $("#btnshowmodal").click(function () {
        $("#loginmodal").modal('show');
    });

    $("#btnhidemodal").click(function () {
        $("#loginmodal").modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Html Code:

```
<div>

<fieldset>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">



                <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginmodal"
                     data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    ×
                                </button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

                                <form>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="column">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" id="listProducts">
                                                    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
                                                        <tr>

                                                            <th>Name</th>
                                                            <th>Video</th>

                                                        </tr>
                                                        @foreach (Workout workout in Model.TemplateWorkouts)
                                                        {
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>@workout.Name
                                                                    <input type="hidden" class="productId" value="@workout.workout_id" /></td>

                                                                <td>
                                                                    <video style="width:250px; height:150px;" src="@Url.Content(workout.link)" controls>
                                                                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                                                    </video>

                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        }
                                                    </table>

                                                </div>


                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div id="cart" style="width:200px; min-height:200px; border:1px solid red;margin-left:300px; padding:5px;">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                @*<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button button4">apply template</button>
                                    <button type="button" id="btnhidemodal" class="btn btn-primary button button4">
                                        hide
                                    </button>*@
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

In WorkoutsController:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(string id)
    {

        if (Session["cart"] == null)
        {
            List<Item> cart = new List<Item>();
            cart.Add(new Item {Workout = new OPPDBContext().Workouts.Where(p=>p.workout_id == Convert.ToInt32(id)).FirstOrDefault() });
            Session["cart"] = cart;
        }
        else
        {
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
            int index = isExist(id);
            if (index != -1)
                index  = 0;
            else
                cart.Add(new Item { Workout = new OPPDBContext().Workouts.Where(p => p.workout_id == Convert.ToInt32(id)).FirstOrDefault() });
            Session["cart"] = cart;
        }
        return Json((List<Item>)Session["cart"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult DeleteFromCart(string id)
    {
        List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
        int index = isExist(id);
        cart.RemoveAt(index);
        Session["cart"] = cart;
        return Json((List<Item>)Session["cart"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private int isExist(string id)
    {
        List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
        for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
            if (cart[i].Workout.workout_id.Equals(id))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
```

The methods are not getting hit at any point. I have confirmed this by setting a breakpoint in the add to cart method.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Can you set a breakpoint at the start of the drop event and see if that gets hit

Comment: Might be due to `<td>` can't be child of `<div>`

Comment: No errors in the console. However, if I drop the td with revert='invalid' is stays in the div for some reason????

Comment: What is the draggable library? Shopify Draggable?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Your code works for me. I get a 404 after the drop. Can you confirm that the API request is being made via the network inspector tab?

Comment: The request was made to Workouts/Workouts/AddToCart/Id. I fixed this by removing removing the Workouts from Workouts/AddToCart. Now I am hitting the expected breakpoint in the controller, but the id is coming back as undefined. Any ideas on how to fix this issue now?

Comment: Solved it. Traversed using .children to get the correct value. Adding to answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request was made to Workouts/Workouts/AddToCart/Id. I fixed this by removing removing the Workouts from Workouts/AddToCart. To get the correct Id value, I changed the js code to as follows:

```
$('#cart').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var productId = $(ui.draggable).children('.productId').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'AddToCart/' + productId,
                success: function (data) {
                    displayCart(data);
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert('failure');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```